# Google is crawling servers files

Tags: php, linux, wordpress, apache, centos

When I searched using the following :

`site:blog.myblog.com`

Then in the result page it is `showing several inappropriate URLs and that on HTTPS`.

For example , the inappropriate URls, are :

https://blog.myblog.com/my-website-on-same-server.com

https://blog.myblog.com/xampp/index.php

`Why it is indexing like this.`

How to fix this? It is really hampering the SEO works for this blog.

I checked for another website on this server and the result is same, the inappropriate URLs and that on HTTPS.

Please guide.

Its on CentOS and xampp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to turn off directory indexing - that's most likely how Google got there. Read here about how to do that: https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/DirectoryListings and to remove the existing indexes, create a robots.txt file and disallow the paths you don't want crawled (here's how to do it http://www.robotstxt.org/)

Comment: Thannk you soo much for the answer. May I know on how robots.txt is created on my server and where to place this file on my server with lines of code please.

Comment: You're welcome. The file is usually placed in the root. More info on the robotstxt.com site :)

Answer (score 0):

Use robots.txt to block certain parts of your website for crawling.

http://www.robotstxt.org/

An other solution would be to password protect the directories you don't want indexed. Most crawlers just ignore these directories because they can't access them.